# HMAC implementation in C with SHA384

Tags: c, sha, hmac

I need an HMAC implementation with SHA384 in C. It is needed for some API I'm writing.
If anyone can provide at least a starting point I would be happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `openssl` library.

An example of using openssl to generate an SHA384 hash is here: http://www.askyb.com/cpp/openssl-sha384-hashing-example-in-cpp/

It claims to be in C++ but it's pretty much straight C.

Comment: Worked. I had to silence the warnings Apple put on openssl, but it went perfect.